# Мой код должен вывести рандомное слово

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Я написал код который выведёт рандомное слово которое вы ввели в начале. Но он выведёт одно слово и всё мне нужен что-бы он вывел ещё рандомное слово(типо после слово которое вывел код когда вы нажимаете что-то он ещё вывел другое рандомное слово)

Мой код:

```
import random

a = int(input("Enter how many options you will have: "))
b = []
for i in range(a):
    u = str(input("Enter " + str(i+1) + " from " + str(a) + ": "))
    b.append(u)

answer = random.randint(0, a-1)


while  True:
    print("Your word is: " + b[answer])
```

Comment: похоже, что рандомные слова тут выводит автор вопроса, а не код. Мало что понятно...

Comment: переведите вопрос на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

У тебя код рабочий просто у тебя раз выбирается рандом а не каждый раз.

```
import random

a = int(input("Enter how many options you will have: "))
b = []

for i in range(a):
    u = str(input("Enter " + str(i+1) + " from " + str(a) + ": "))
    b.append(u)

while  True:
    answer = random.randint(0, a-1)
    print("Your word is: " + b[answer])
```

Comment: Потом-же это всё идёт бесконечно как остонавить?

Comment: У тебя проблема в том что все шло подряд с одинаковым индексом. А чтобы не было бесконечности лучше используй либо for либо поставь какое-то условие